# What is com command in linux?

Tags: command-line, terminal, usb, command, serial-port

I saw in a video on Youtube :

```
$ sudo com /dev/ttyUSb0 115200
[sudo] password for xt003:
setting speed 115200
C-a exit,  C-a modem lines status
[status]: RTS DTR
```

What is `com` command?

I searched for `com` on google but I didn't find any helpful thing.

during the video an USB to TTL UART dongle was connected.

video link(it is not english but may be helpful): https://youtu.be/1wr99YXCnbA

Comment: Look for `minicom` - serial console.

Comment: Do not tag things as the Bourne Again shell just because they happen to relate somehow to a command line, The Bourne Again shell is not a generic term for command-line stuff.  This is especially so _when the person in the video is quite clearly using the Z shell_.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at [`tinyserial`](http://tinyserial.sourceforge.net).

I identified this the hard way, from only the prompt in the question.
The shamefully easy way to identify this, that I discovered afterwards when I went to watch the video, is to simply pay attention when watching the video; because the presenter tells us that it is `com` from the `tinyserial` package *as xe is typing in* the text "`/dev/ttyUSB0`".

Answer (score 0):

I have used `com` in the past -- I suspect on Solaris (maybe even SunOS), and long ago. It is used to configure various communications characteristics like speed, parity, Xon/Xoff, timeouts. Here, it is being used to set the bit-rate to 115200 baud.

The Linux equivalent appears to be `stty`.

To discover what goes on under the hood, more detailed explanations, or just for a better sleep pattern: `man -s 3 termios`.